# Extra plot window and crash with matplotlib and pyqt on windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pyqt

I have a strange problem with a python code that works perfectly fine on Ubuntu but not on Windows.
I'm embedding a matplotlib figure in a PyQt5 QWidget. However, I get an extra window on Windows, that is empty. 
Also, at some, it eventually crashes and the IPython session just stops without any error message.

Nothing of this happens on my Ubuntu python framework, even though the versions are the same for all packages...

Any ideas of what could cause that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

And here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QFileDialog, QApplication, QMessageBox,      
QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, 
QFrame, QCheckBox)
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import \\
FigureCanvasQTAgg as  FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as \\
NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib

from .subPlotsFormat import subplotsFormat



class QENSPlot(QWidget):
    """ This class created a PyQt widget containing a matplotlib canvas 
    to draw the plots,
    a lineedit widget to allow the user to select the q-value to be used 
    to show the data
    and several buttons corresponding to the different type of plots.

    Plot        -> plot the normalized experimental data for the selected 
                   q-value
    Compare     -> superimpose experimental data on one plot
    3D Plot     -> plot the whole normalized dataSet
    Analysis    -> plot the different model parameters as a function of 
                   q-value
    Resolution  -> plot the fitted model on top of the experimental data 
                   for the selected q-value """

def __init__(self, datasetList):

    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    super().__init__()

    #_Dataset related attributes
    self.dataset = datasetList

    try:
        self.initChecks()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return


    #_A figure instance to plot on
    self.figure = plt.figure()

    #_This is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
    #_it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init__
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, self.figure)

    #_Add some interactive elements
    self.button = QPushButton('Plot')
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)

    self.compareButton = QPushButton('Compare')
    self.compareButton.clicked.connect(self.compare)

    self.analysisButton = QPushButton('Analysis')
    self.analysisButton.clicked.connect(self.analysisPlot)

    self.qWiseAnalysisButton = QPushButton('q-wise analysis')
    self.qWiseAnalysisButton.clicked.connect(self.qWiseAnalysis)

    self.plot3DButton = QPushButton('3D Plot')
    self.plot3DButton.clicked.connect(self.plot3D)

    self.fitButton = QPushButton('Fit')
    self.fitButton.clicked.connect(self.fitPlot)

    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

    self.boxLine = QFrame()
    self.boxLine.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
    self.boxLine.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)

    self.label = QLabel('Q value to plot', self)
    self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self) 
    self.lineEdit.setText('0.8')

    self.errBox = QCheckBox("Plot errors", self)



    #_Set the layout
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.canvas, stretch=1)
    layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
    layout.addWidget(self.boxLine)
    layout.addWidget(self.label)
    layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
    layout.addWidget(self.errBox)
    layout.addWidget(self.button)
    layout.addWidget(self.compareButton)
    layout.addWidget(self.plot3DButton)
    layout.addWidget(self.analysisButton)
    layout.addWidget(self.qWiseAnalysisButton)
    layout.addWidget(self.fitButton)
    self.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: Try not to mix pyplot with your custom GUI. Remove `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and see e.g. [Embedding in Qt](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html) for how to get a figure.

Comment: Indeed, thanks! I didn't realize mixing with pyplot could cause this.It works better now everything is managed through the canvas figure.